# Duplicate each element in a Haskell List

Tags: haskell

by functions 
How can I duplicate every element of a list with itself twice. e.g. duplicate `[1,3,5]` should return `[1,1,3,3,5,5]` ?

and replace an element by some other element in a list. e.g. replace 3 30 `[1, 3 ,4 ,5, 3, 4]` should return `[1, 30, 4, 5, 30, 4]`

I'm quite new in Haskell and need to submit a homework today.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
duplicateEach  = (>>= replicate 2)
duplicateEach2 = concatMap (replicate 2)
duplicateEach3 xs = [ y | x <- xs, y<-[x,x] ]

import Data.List.Split

replaceOne f t xs = [ y | x<-xs, let y = if x==f then t else x]

replaceSublist f t = intercalate t . sepBy f   -- f and t is lists
```

Comment: @luqui I found this useful years later - one person's homework is another person's... not homework?

Comment: hey, I'll sub for someone in an entire class for those delicious internet points

Answer (score 12):

Map over the elements and replicate them. Then concatenate the results:

```
concatMap (replicate 2) [1,3,5]
```

For the second issue, look at [`Data.List.Utils`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/0.18.6/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3Areplace)

```
replace [3] [30] [1,3,4,5,3,4]
```

Comment: duplicatelist xs = concatMap (replicate) xs does not work for me ?

Comment: `duplicateList = concatMap (replicate 2)` Works for me. (`duplicateList [1,2] == [1,1,2,2]`)

Comment: @Nobre: It appears you can't even copy and paste code properly. I gave you everything you needed to know (probably more than I should have given you). if you can't make functions out of this stuff yourself then you don't deserve to pass the subject you're studying. I'm quite stunned that this has been downvoted twice to be honest.

Comment: Not downvoted as much as nickela's answer. Maybe you were downvoted because you said too much.

Answer (score 3):

For the first one:

```
duplicate_each xs = foldr dup [] xs
    where dup x y = x : x : y
```

At least for me, it is a clearer solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could think about each function as a sequence of steps:

> by functions How can I duplicate every
>   element of a list with itself twice.

To duplicate each element of a list *xs*, you need to apply a function which, given an argument *x*, returns the list [*x*, *x*], to each element of the list; since this produces a list of lists, you will need to concatenates the results. The concatenated list is the list with each element duplicated:

```
k :: a -> [a]
k x = [x,x]

g :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
g f [] = []
g f (x:xs) = f x : g f xs

duplicate :: [a] -> [a]
duplicate = concat . (g k)
```

Since `g = map` and `concat . g = concatMap`, the function you are looking for is:

```
duplicate :: [a] -> [a]
duplicate =  concatMap (\x -> [x,x])
          => concatMap (replicate 2)
```

To replace an element *a* by a value *b*, iterate over the list with a function which exchanges *b* for *a*:

```
f :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> a
f o r x = if x == o then r else x

replaceOn :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceOn o r [] = []
replaceOn o r (x:xs) = f o r x : h o r xs
```

Since `h = map f`, you have:

```
replaceOn :: a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceOn o r = map (\x -> if x == o then r else x)
```

I'm not a Haskell expert. However, it helps me to break Haskell problems into sequences of "returned values". These are like "steps" in an imperative language. The steps are composed using combinators, higher order functions, and ordering of functions. You can think about sequencing like: do *f* to get *x*; to *g* with *f x* to get *x'*, etc.