# How to control laziness on example of Double each element of list

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I tried to solve [Duplicate each element in a Haskell List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448803/duplicate-each-element-in-a-haskell-list) task and make it as a full program, that write the list to standard output

Here is my solution

```
main :: IO ()
main = getList >>= return . doubleEachItem >>= putStrLn . show

getList = return [1,3,5]

doubleEachItem :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleEachItem = foldr (++) [] . map (take 2 . repeat)
```

But when I try to process really long list

```
getList = return . take 10000000000 $ repeat 15
```

the program terminated with out of memory error.

The question is: how I can improve the program, so it would be able to process lists of any size?

**Edit:**

I think program crashed because I run it with `runghc` command. In that case ghc consume about 3Gbytes of memory and was killed by operating system. The output file after crash was only about 0.6GBytes. The reason of such behavior is unclear for me.

When I compile the program to native executable `ghc haskell03.hs -o haskell03` and execute it with redirection to a file `./haskell03 >out03.txt` it perfectly runs in constant memory space and produces output file with speed about 20MBytes/sec. When the program finished the output file takes 57GBytes. Total execution time was 47 minutes.

Comment: I don't see any problem when running the same code on my machine.

Comment: Style note:  `foo >>= return . bar` is the same thing as `fmap bar foo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh!  I think I know what's going on.  This is subtle.

`runghc` runs in interpreted mode, as if you had loaded an run the file through `ghci`. `getList` is a top-level binding, so its value (and all values it references) are cached.  That means that GHC was trying to cache your entire ten billion element array.

You might think that if you inlined the list it would work:

```
main = putStrLn . show . doubleEachElement $ [1..10^10]
```

But not so, because `main` is a top-level binding as well, and it references `[1..10^10]`, so the giant unfolded version of that list will be cached there as well.

The general rule is, when something doesn't depend on the input, it can be cached.  So you can fix this by making it appear to depend on the input.  In interpreted mode, GHC is not very smart about this, so it's fairly easy to trick it:

```
main = do
    n <- return (10^10)
    putStrLn . show . doubleEachElement $ [1..n]
```

This would work with your `getList` as well, if `getList` took a parameter instead of hard-coding `10^10`.

Fortunately, in compiled mode, GHC looks harder at the uses of these top-level symbols, so it can see that the list is only used once, and thus can begin garbage collecting its heads as it is output.

This problem does not come up in the real world very often, because programs often depend heavily on their input, so there aren't any top level big constants like this.  But yeah, it can be a pain when GHC tries to cache something you don't want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly lazy, it doesn't need any optimization. What is probably going on is that all the output is on a single line, which is being buffered.  You can fix this by turning off buffering:

```
import System.IO
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    getList >>= ...
```

Or by, say, printing each number on its own line

```
main = getList >>= return . doubleEachItem >>= mapM_ print
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am completely new to Haskell so any comment is valuable for me. Unfortunately this solution does not help in case when I run my program with runghc. Without buffering ghc produces the output very slowly but still consumes memory.

Comment: @sign, hmm, that's odd.  Very slowly?  Did you try the `mapM_ print` solution?

Comment: I just followed a reddit link to one of your answers that named you as Luke Palmer, and indeed your profile links to your blog, but for some reason, even though I've browsed your blog before, and several times linked to the "existential typeclass antipattern" entry, I never really put the two together in my mind. In any case, today's the day I realised that the Luke Palmer blog author I have a lot of respect for is the same person as the luqui answer author I have a lot of respect for, and that made me happy.

Answer (score 1):

This the application of answer of **luqui** to original program from the question with minimum modification

```
main :: IO ()
main = return 1 >>= getList >>= return . doubleEachElement >>= putStrLn . show

getList doNotCache = return . take (10^10) $ repeat 15

doubleEachElement :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleEachElement = foldr (++) [] . map (take 2 . repeat)
```

The changes are emphasized with bold.

As luqui has shown, getList was cached because it was constant expression. But we can make haskell to believe that it is not constant simply by providing dummy argument, dependent on input.

Answer (score -1):

Your doubleEachItem implementation via `foldr` require whole list constructed in memory, because `foldr` beginning work from end of list. To avoid this, replace `foldr` to `foldl'` or rewrite function as:

```
doubleEachItem = concatMap (replicate 2)
```

Comment: `foldr` only needs to work from the end of the list in a strict language.  `foldr` is the lazier of the two folds in a lazy language.  Try `take 10 $ doubleEachItem [1..]` and watch give you 10 numbers.

Comment: From http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html: `concatMap f = concat . map f` ; `concat xss = foldr (++) [] xss` ; `replicate n x = take n (repeat x)`.  So your definition is exactly equivalent to his.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am unfamiliar with Haskell "sugar" operators so this comment is valuable for me.

Comment: @luqui Much thank you. Before this I haven't understand completely laziness of Haskell.